Add markers for only some groups, no markers for all other groups
I am making a plot in plotly using data on aggreagreted demographic groups. I want the user to be able to control what groups and what time periods are shown so I am also using crosstalk.
I want the lines to visually indicate what kind of data is shown, so data on the entire population is a solid line with no markers, different age groups have different line types and no markers, while men and women have solid lines but different markers. I can't achieve having no markers for all data execpt the data shown for men and women respectively. Here is what my attempt looks like:
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  value = runif(15, min = -1, max = 1),
  time  = rep(c(1, 2, 3), 5),
  group = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), each = 3),
  sex   = c(rep(c('Male', 'Female'), each = 3), rep('All', 9)),
  age   = c(rep('All', 9), rep(c('Young', 'Old'), each = 3))
  ) %>% 
  mutate(type = case_when(sex != 'All' ~ sex, age != 'All' ~ age, T ~ 'All'))

sd <- highlight_key(df)

widgets <- bscols(
  filter_slider('ti', 'Time', sd, ~time, round = T),
  filter_checkbox('ty', 'Type', sd, ~type)
)

lt <- c('All' = 'solid', 'Young' = 'dash', 'Old' = 'dot')
syms <- c('All' = '', 'Male' = '138', 'Female' = '134')

plot <- plot_ly(sd, x = ~time, y = ~value, mode = 'lines+markers', 
  type = 'scatter', color = ~group, linetype = ~age, symbol = ~sex,
  symbols = syms)

bscols(widgets, plot)

...where I try to remove markers for rows having sex==all with All == '' when defining syms. However, this just results in a warning and then all, old and young gets a circle as marker.
In a purely plotly context I can get the desired visualization by add_trace for each group individually:
df_no_markers <- df %>% filter(sex == 'All')
df_with_markers <- df %>% filter(sex != 'All')

plot <- plot_ly(sd) %>%
  add_trace(data = df_no_markers, x = ~time, y = ~value, color = ~group,
    mode = 'lines', linetype = ~age) %>%
  add_trace(data = df_with_markers, x = ~time, y = ~value, color = ~group,
    mode = 'lines+markers', linetype = I('solid'), symbol = ~sex, symbols = syms)

...but that disconnects it from the widgets, i.e., then I can't control which lines are shown using the widgets.

You could work around the unwanted markers by setting the size to zero for the sex = All lines.
plot <- plot_ly(sd, x = ~time, y = ~value, mode = 'lines+markers', 
                type = 'scatter', color = ~group, 
                marker = list(size = ~ifelse(sex == "All", 0, 5)), 
                linetype = ~age, symbol = ~sex,
                symbols = syms) 


corrected symbols to syms but for some reason this gives a plot where 'All', 'Old' has very large circles, and 'Young', 'Female' and 'Male' has very small markers. Inverting the logical to ~ifelse(sex == "All", 10, 0)) then gives large markers to 'Female' and 'Male' but also to 'Young'...

Ah, if you add as.factor to the group in the data frame group = as.factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), each = 3)), it should work.

it does indeed! Would you care to explain why that change made the difference (I can't transfer it to my real data, i.e., when i as.factor the column im using for color, it still doesnt work

That is a really good question - I've been playing around with it, and marker = list(size = ~ifelse(age == "All", 0, 5)) seems to suppress the unwanted markers without having to turn group into a factor. I have yet to find out why.

in my own data it seems that the ordering of the rows infleunces what markers have what size. I think the answer may lie somewhere in the fact that add_lines() draw according to ordering of x cf. here (https://plotly-r.com/scatter-traces) and that may collide in setting marker size if the rows are not ordered according to x since ifelse produces a vector of integers which are ordered according to the rows.
I am keeping the question open in case someone can shed some more light on the issue and if they have a less hacky solution than changing size of markers to 0. But thanks for the help!
